# C++ Win32 loading multiple bitmaps in WM_CREATE won't load

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I am trying to load some bitmaps when starting up the application. I am trying to load them in `WM_CREATE` but only the last bitmap i load will stay loaded.

I can load the pictures in `WM_PAINT` but i have been told it's better to load them in `WM_CREATE`.

```
//before switch statement
static HBITMAP bitmap1, bitmap2;

case WM_CREATE: {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    bitmap1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
            IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

    bitmap2 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2),
        IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

    if (!bitmap1 || !bitmap2) MessageBox(NULL, _T("Error while loading images"), _T("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

case WM_PAINT:{
    //Draw bitmap...
}
```

I expected that both bitmaps got loaded as they do when loaded inside `WM_PAINT`

**EDIT:**

The problem weren't were i thought. The problem is it draws behind the filled area i had made. I still don't know how to fix.

```
//Draw bitmap function
bool DrawBitmap(HBITMAP hBitmap, int posX, int posY, int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    BITMAP bmp;

    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(windowClassName, NULL);
    if (!hWnd) return false;

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    if (!hdc) return false;

    HDC hBitmapDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    if (!hBitmapDC) return false;

    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);

    SelectObject(hBitmapDC, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, hBitmapDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hBitmapDC);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    return true;
}

//Before switch
RECT recRect;
STATIC HBITMAP bitmap1;

//case WM_CREATE:
case WM_CREATE: {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    bitmap1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
            IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
    if (!bitmap) MessageBox(NULL, _T("Error while loading images"), _T("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
    break;

//case WM_PAINT
case WM_PAINT:
    DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    recRect = { -1, -1, 50 + 1, 30 + 1 };
    FillRect(hdc, &recRect, (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(30, 30, 30)));


    if (DrawBitmap(bitmap1, 5, 5, 10, 10) == false) MessageBox(NULL, _T("Error while drawing images"), _T("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
    break;
```

The problem does not occur when i declare the bitmap in `WM_PAINT`

Comment: You should be calling `GetLastError` on each of those calls to LoadImage, not just ignoring the error(s) that may have occurred.  See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew)

Comment: but shouldn't it return NULL if there is an error?

Comment: Yes, if it returns NULL, then you need to immediately call `GetLastError` to get more information.  You made two mistakes in attempting to diagnose the issue -- 1) You failed to call GetLastError to get more information, and 2) You made one call to LoadBitmap, and instead of checking the return value of that call, you made another call to LoadBitmap.  Each call requires an error check and a GetLastError() if the bitmap is NULL, and not wait around until you feel like testing for null return values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In the `documentation` it says `If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.` but it's not `NULL` that is what i am checking with `if (!bitmap1)` so why should i check with `GetLastError`

Comment: You do know that `!bitmap1` is a null check, right?  So you *are* checking for NULL, but you are checking too late.  You should be checking for NULL right after you call `LoadBitmap`.  Your code that checks is not correct.  `bitmap1 = LoadBitmap(); if (!bitmap1) { DWORD errorVal = GetLastError(); display_error_message_and_error_value;}`  Then if `bitmap1` is not NULL,  **then** you load bitmap2 using the same logic.  You shouldn't load every bitmap first and delay the check -- you lose all information on faultily loaded bitmaps by using that kind of logic.

Comment: Do you really not have a `break;` between `WM_CREATE` and `WM_PAINT` ?

Comment: The code is OK. You just need to check the return values of `bitmap1` and `bitmap2`, whether the `MessageBox` you set pops up, and if `bitmap1` or `bitmap2` is NULL, then set `GetLasterror ()`, like this: `bitmap1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
   IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
  int i = GetLastError();
  bitmap2 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2),
   IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
  int j = GetLastError();`   Check the values of i and j to determine the cause of the error.

Comment: And you need to set `break`, otherwise the program will continue to execute `WM_PAINT` after executing `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: I have made it `break` and i check the error with `GetLastError();` if it returns `NULL` but i doesn't return `NULL`. But it's still not loading the bitmaps do anyone have an idea what the error could be then?

Comment: If both `bitmap1` and `bitmap2` are loaded successfully then there are no problems in that step. Show how you are drawing the bitmaps. Minimum reproducible code...

Comment: Your paint code is wrong and you have a lot of resource leaks. What is `FindWindow(windowClassName, NULL)`? Are you trying to paint on another process? This is not supported in Windows, even if you have limited success on your system. Or do you simply want to paint 2 bitmaps in your own window?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I am trying to paint on my own window and its the class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `GetWindowDC` returns the dc for the whole window, including the non-client area. You usually need `GetDC` instead.
2. Always use `BeginPaint/EndPaint` when responding to `WM_PAINT` and return 0.
3. `CreateSolidBrush` is a GDI resource leak. After creating brush or other GDI objects, you have to destroy those objects, otherwise you have resource leak, the program will crash after 10,000 GDI leaks.
4. In your draw function you have `DeleteObject(hBitmap)` This will destroy the bitmap immediately. But you probably want to keep the bitmap handle and destroy it only after the program is finished.

Suggestion:

```
bool DrawBitmap(HDC hdc, HBITMAP hBitmap, int posX, int posY, int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HGDIOBJ oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    return true;
}

...
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    HBRUSH hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, hbrush);
    DeleteObject(hbrush); 

    BITMAP bm1;
    GetObject(bitmap1, sizeof(bm1), &bm1);
    DrawBitmap(hdc, bitmap1, 0, 0, bm1.bmWidth, bm1.bmHeight);

    int x = bm1.bmWidth;
    int y = bm1.bmHeight;
    BITMAP bm2;
    GetObject(bitmap2, sizeof(bm2), &bm2);
    DrawBitmap(hdc, bitmap2, x, y, bm2.bmWidth, bm2.bmHeight);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}

case WM_DESTROY:
    DeleteObject(bitmap1);
    DeleteObject(bitmap2);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
```